# User controlled grid size for triangle made of *'s in Assembly Language

Tags: loops, assembly, machine-code

Enter grid size (1-9):3

```
*

**

***
```

Here's the code i have so far:

```
.ORIG x3000


        LEA  R0, PRINT

        LEA  R1, MEMSPAC
        PUTS
        GETC
        PUTC
M       STR  R0, R1, #0
N       .FILL M
        LD   R1, N       
        NOT  R1, R1

        ADD  R1, R1, #1   ; R1 = -N


        AND  R2, R2, #0   ; R2 = holds number of *'s to be printed



LOOPA   LEA  R0, NEWLN


        PUTS    


        ADD  R3, R2, R1   ; while (R2 < N)


        BRzp LOOPB      
        ADD  R5, R5, #1   ;


        ADD  R4, R4, #1


LOOPC   LD   R0, STAR     ; R0 = *


        OUT               ; Write *

        ADD  R5, R5, #-1
        BRp  LOOPC
        ADD  R5, R4, #0
        ADD  R2, R2, #1 ;

        BRnzp    LOOPA
LOOPB   
        LEA  R0, NEWLN


        PUTS            

        STOP    HALT        

STAR    .FILL    x2A

RIP     TRAP x25

PRINT   .STRINGZ "Enter grid size (1-9):"

NEWLN   .STRINGZ "\n"

MEMSPAC .blkw 100
        .END
```

This code works and it prints the triangle. However it goes into an infinite loop rather than printing  grid size of 3. If i change the code "N    .FILL  M" to "N      .FILL   3" it will print out grid size of 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is your architecture and assembler? Is it really an infinite loop, not a loop of about x3000 times?

Comment: Sorry i'm using the LC3 Assembler

Comment: And what, in your opinion, is `N .FILL M` supposed to do?